# How to test nested HTTP requests in JS

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, web-api-testing

I'm working with an external API that gives me 3 seconds to respond - in order to avoid timeout, I respond with 200 immediately and then hit the API again, once I'm ready to send a proper response (the API gives me a `response_url` that I can use to make requests for 30 minutes).

Unfortunately, that makes my code hard to test. I don't know how to detect whether the 2nd request is happening and whether it has correct data.

Here's my endpoint handler:

```
const handler = (payload, response) => {
// Respond with 200 right away to avoid timeout
response.status(200).end()

getData.then((data) => {
    const responseURL = payload.response_url

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: responseURL,
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data
    }

    request(options).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.error)
    })
})
```

}

If I wasn't responding with 200 right away, I would test the endpoint with `chai` and make sure that the response has all the right fields. Right now, I don't know how to test the second request that has the actual data that I care about.

Is there any way I can 'watch' the 2nd endpoint and be notified when it's hit so that I can inspect the data?

Comment: where does `getData` come from? this looks like anti pattern for me...anyway, you can see each xhr request in your browsers development tools

Comment: Take the functions out and test them in isolation?